# How do i get the time it took for an input to be written

Tags: python, input, time

I need to record the time it took to write an input

in my code i want to record the time (in an
 int) it took for the user to input a string and compare it to a high score.
i tried to use a while string that was dependent on a boolean being true, inside the loop i added 1 to an integer so it would repeat adding one until the user finished inputting and the boolean turned to false
then i wold get the value of the int and compare it to the high score

Comment: Please add a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
import time
start = time.time()
foo = input('input a string')
elapsed = time.time() - start #milliseceonds.
```